# Number of overtakes in a race

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

Im given an input array racers of length N where each racer has it own *speed*,
`(1 <= speed[i] <= 10^8)` and *starting position*. Racers move on a infinitly long track in the same direction.(from left to right)

 Racers array is sorted in **ascending order** based on positions meaning:
`1 <= positions[0] < positions[1] < ... < positions[n] < 10^9`.
I want to calculate how many *overtakes* would occur until *first racer* reaches position **position**, `racers[0].Position < position < racers[n].Position`.
Overtake occurs when racer A's position *is equal* to racer B's position( it can happen when racer A's position had a smaller value than racer B's position but racer A's speed is greater than racer B's speed).

My idea looks like this:

```
static uint OvertakingCountAtPosition(Racer[] racers, double position, uint racerCount)
{
    var overtakingCount = 0u;

    for (int i = 0; i < racerCount; i++)
    {
        var time1 = (position - racers[i].Position) / racers[i].Speed;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < racerCount; j++)
        {
            var time2 = (position - racers[j].Position) / racers[j].Speed;
            if (0.0001d >= time1 - time2)
            {
               overtakingCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    return overtakingCount;
}
```

Basically, I choose one racer and calculate the time he needed to go to from his position to the given position. Then, I go trough the rest of the array and find time needed for other racers in front of him to reach target position. When I compare two racers, I check if second racer needed more or equal time to go to target position then first racer. If that is true, I can say that there was an overtake. Once an overtake occured, those two racers wont be able to overtake each other again.
I think problem can be solved in a better way but for now im looking for a working solution.

Comment: What language is the shown code written in?

Comment: Code is written in c#

Comment: More importantly maybe: what's your question? Where are you stuck? And if you are, what is the outcome, the expected outcome and steps you've performed trying to correct it?

Comment: I think my question is pretty clear. I need to find number of overtakes in a race.  Im stuck since my code doesn't work and I am not quite sure whats wrong. Expected outcome is that number. I tried covering some edge cases but I am not sure what those are and whether I might miss something.

Comment: " I need to find number of overtakes in a race". No that's your **assignment**. Explain your results and how they differ and what you've done to debug your code.

Comment: As you are clearly starting off, I'd suggest you try and spit the question into parts without trying to optimize things. So first go through all racers and see which one gets to the given position first. Then you can create an array of the locations where each player finishes. Then go through the array of players and test them against those with a higher index (to avoid duplicate comparisons): if they started up lower but did end up higher then they've overtaken their opponent and you can increase the count. By creating one loop you're making it harder for yourself; divide the problem!

Comment: Can you show me some snippet?

Comment: Nah, that's your job. I've just given you three steps, why not create a function description for each of them and try to fill in the code after that? By the way, I'd normally use floating point for this problem.

Comment: Ok. You are right, I shouldn't use uints but rather use floats.

Comment: Well, don't accept that too easily. Surely the data type should depend on the actual problem being solved, not on whim. BTW this problem sounds to me as if it was a competitive programming problem, if so could you include the original wording of the problem and (if they have them) test cases. If you have to solve this for several different positions (with the same racers) that would be of particular interest. And if this is from competitive programming, you're probably expected to solve this *exactly*, with no floating point nonsense.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Keep to the problem description if there is any. For real life, use real numbers ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, since you just need an `overtakeCount` you don't necessarily need to calculate times, since its infinite track you just need to check the position of the racer and if the racer in front is slower.

solving for total overtakes in a race (not `until first racer reaches position position`) could look something along the lines:

```cs
//loop the following while racers are not in final position
for (int r1 = 0; r1 < racers.Length; r1++)
{
    for (int r2 = 0; r2 < racers.Length; r2++)
    {
        if (racers[r2].position == racers[r1].position - 1)
        {
            if (racers[r1].speed > racers[r2].speed)
            {
                racers[r1].position--;
                racers[r2].position++;

                overtakes++;
            }
        }   
    }           
}
```

Edit: I decided to improve on my previous solution since you don't appear to need a step by step iteration, for the sake of example chose the types I found most convenient for the sample but they are easily changed.

The change is simple, I just check the relative position instead of checking if is right in front: (also tidy up the code)

```cs
for (int r1 = 0; r1 < racers.Length; r1++)
{
    for (int r2 = 0; r2 < racers.Length; r2++)
    {
        if (racers[r1].speed <= racers[r2].speed)
            continue;

        if(racers[r1].startingPosition <= racers[r2].startingPosition)
            continue;

        overtakes++;
    }
}
```

[sample](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

See the results in a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hetifxkicf)

- x is position
- y is time

[image: graph]

Note: I suggest you edit the question to more clearly elaborate the issue, not just drop an assignment with a proposed solution but explain step by step what is wrong with your solution, what you expect a solution to look like and overall simplify the question, we don't really need to know the max speed is specifically 10^8 for example `speed ranges from 1 to maxSpeed` its more readable and would work the same in any algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the suggested algorithm in terms of an example. I have written calculations in Ruby but readers unfamiliar with that language can view it as pseudo-code. It should be a straightforward exercise to convert it to C#.

**Data**

Suppose

```
position = 6
```

and the racers are as follows:

```
racers = [ { :pos=>2, :speed=>2.1 },
           { :pos=>3, :speed=>2.0 },
           { :pos=>4, :speed=>1.0 },
           { :pos=>5, :speed=>0.2 },
           { :pos=>7, :speed=>3.0 },
           { :pos=>8, :speed=>2.0 },
           { :pos=>9, :speed=>1.8 } ]
```

**Step 1: Partition `racers` between those who have not yet reached `position = 6` and those who have**

```
before, after = racers.partition { |racer| racer[:pos] < position }
before
  #=> [{:pos=>2, :speed=>2.1},
  #    {:pos=>3, :speed=>2.0},
  #    {:pos=>4, :speed=>1.0},
  #    {:pos=>5, :speed=>0.2}]
after
  #=> [{:pos=>7, :speed=>3.0},
  #    {:pos=>8, :speed=>2.0},
  #    {:pos=>9, :speed=>1.8}]
```

Order must be preserved in the sense that `before + after` must equal `racers`.

**Step 2: Determine time it takes each "before" racer to reach `position`**

```
times_to_reach_position = before.map do |h|
  (position - h[:pos])/h[:speed]
end
  #=> [1.9047619047619047, 1.5, 2.0, 5.0]
```

**Step 3: Determine time until first "before" car reaches `position`**

```
time = times_to_reach_position.min
  #=>1.5
```

**Step 4: Determine position of each car at time `time` and save positional order**

```
def m4(arr)
  arr.each_with_index do |h,i|
    h[:new_pos] = h[:pos] + time * h[:speed]
    h[:order] = i
  end    
end

m4(before)
  #=> [{:pos=>2, :speed=>2.1, :new_pos=>5.15, :order=>0},
  #    {:pos=>3, :speed=>2.0, :new_pos=>6.0,  :order=>1},
  #    {:pos=>4, :speed=>1.0, :new_pos=>5.5,  :order=>2},
  #    {:pos=>5, :speed=>0.2, :new_pos=>5.3,  :order=>3}]

m4(after)
  #=> [{:pos=>7, :speed=>3.0, :new_pos=>11.5, :order=>0},
  #    {:pos=>8, :speed=>2.0, :new_pos=>11.0, :order=>1},
  #    {:pos=>9, :speed=>1.8, :new_pos=>11.7, :order=>2}]
```

**Step 5: Sort before and after by `:new_pos`**

```
def m5(arr)
  # sort in place
  arr.sort_by! { |h| h[:new_pos] }
end

m5(before)
  #=> [{:pos=>2, :speed=>2.1, :new_pos=>5.15, :order=>0},
  #    {:pos=>5, :speed=>0.2, :new_pos=>5.3,  :order=>3},
  #    {:pos=>4, :speed=>1.0, :new_pos=>5.5,  :order=>2},
  #    {:pos=>3, :speed=>2.0, :new_pos=>6.0,  :order=>1}]

m5(after)
  #=> [{:pos=>8, :speed=>2.0, :new_pos=>11.0, :order=>1},
  #    {:pos=>7, :speed=>3.0, :new_pos=>11.5, :order=>0},
  #    {:pos=>9, :speed=>1.8, :new_pos=>11.7, :order=>2}]
```

**Step 6: Compute total number of overtakes**

```
def m6(arr)
  count = 0
  arr.each_with_index { |h,i| count += [i-h[:order], 0].max }
  count
end

m6(before) + m6(after)
  #=> 3
```

As seen the car originally at position 3 passed cars originally in positions 4 and 5 and the car originally at position 7 passed the car originally at position 8.